# databinding formatted text to a richtextbox in silverlight 4

Tags: data-binding, silverlight-4.0, richtextbox

I need to databind formatted text to a RichTextBox. For formatting it seems that I will have to create a series of Runs with their specific formats and then add them to a paragraph and add it to the blocks property on the RichTextBox. I tried to bind a paragraph property to Blocks but it doesn't seem to allow that. Paragraph doesn't have an itemsource to bind it to a list of Runs. How can I possibly databind the list of Runs to a RichTextBox Widget ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with.  I created a custom RichTextViewer class and inherited from RichTextBox.

```
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace System.Windows.Controls
{
    public class RichTextViewer : RichTextBox
    {
        public const string RichTextPropertyName = "RichText";

        public static readonly DependencyProperty RichTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(RichTextPropertyName,
                                        typeof (string),
                                        typeof (RichTextBox),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(
                                            new PropertyChangedCallback
                                                (RichTextPropertyChanged)));

        public RichTextViewer()
        {
            IsReadOnly = true;
            Background = new SolidColorBrush {Opacity = 0};
            BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
        }

        public string RichText
        {
            get { return (string) GetValue(RichTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(RichTextProperty, value); }
        }

        private static void RichTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        {
            ((RichTextBox) dependencyObject).Blocks.Add(
                XamlReader.Load((string) dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue) as Paragraph);

        }
    }
}
```